# What is meant by "declaration of brain stem death is made mandatory for every hospital"?

Tags: brain, death, organ-donation, brain-damage

I am an activist working for organ donation popularization in India, a country with a dismally low rate (0.5 per million). Apart from working for deceased donation, I had also offered my own organs as a living donor, but the donation couldn't go through due to unfortunate legal hurdles in unrelated living donation in India.

While reading a [recent paper](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s12055-021-01170-9) on the challenges, I found the following:

> Sensitization of doctors regarding brain stem death declaration is one
> of the biggest challenges encountered by the transplant programme in
> India.
>
> A major change in the transplant laws can significantly increase the
> deceased donor pool if declaration of brain stem death is made
> mandatory for every hospital.

*Could the experts here please elaborate, in some detail, what is meant here? How are the brain stem deaths dealt with now, in the absence of such a law? Is it not reported/communicated? Are only the authorities not informed? Or is the family also not informed? Why is a separate law needed? How is it legal to not inform a death?*

In other words, my question is what exactly is lacking today and why?

Thank you so much for this community. Your answer will guide my activist group's efforts.

Comment: "A major change in the transplant laws..." The user answering this question would need to be familiar with medicine and transplant laws in India. This is more of a legal question than a medical one. The laws in the US are not applicable to the laws required for organ donation in India.

Comment: Ignore the migration notice at the top of the question. The question has been reopened here. It's up to the Law.SE mods to decide whether they will close it there, but given that it now has good answers they may not.